# Touch/Tap method issue when used in calabash-ios console

Tags: ios, ruby, calabash, calabash-ios

I have tried several times . Even in a blog post it was mention to "start_test_server_in_background" so that gesture related commands to work .
I have tried that as well . still it says NoMethod Found Error

touch("button id:'id_name'")

even i used tap method .

I am using calabash 0.21.4 latest one 
and
i am running the command on calabash-ios console .

Comment: Do you have some example code to show so we can better help you?

Comment: calabash-ios console is where we enter our commands  and it displays in iphone simulator according to the command .Like Example  : calabash-ios 0.21.4> touch("button id:'Login'")
NoMethodError: undefined method `touch' for nil:NilClass
 from /Users/shubhopramanik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.21.4/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:1935:in `query_action_with_options'
 from /Users/shubhopramanik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.21.4/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:290:in `touch'
 from (irb):16
 from /Users/shubhopramanik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Answer (score -1):

my example, but calabash-android:

1. cd directory of apk
2. calabash-android resign XXX.apk
3. calabsh-android console XXX.apk
4. start_test_server_in_background